# how to merge 2 different rdd in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I m trying to merge 2 rdds to one. If my rdd1 consists of 2 records of 2 elements both are strings ex: 
key_A:value_A and Key_B:value_B

rdd2 also consists of 1 record of 2 elements both of which are strings 
key_C:value_c

my final rdd would look like this:
key_A :value_A   ,   Key_B :value_B ,     key_C :value_c

we can use union method of rdd but its not working . Plz kindly help
while using union of 2 rdds should the row of the 2 differnt rdd contain the same no of elments or there size can differ.......??

Comment: "we can use union method of rdd but its not working" - show the code you tried, and explain what's "not working" (show expected result vs. actual result / exception)

Comment: @Swaroop : Since you said both are String's `union` should work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try with join:

```
join(otherDataset, [numTasks])
```

When called on datasets of type (K, V) and (K, W), returns a dataset of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of elements for each key. Outer joins are supported through leftOuterJoin, rightOuterJoin, and fullOuterJoin.

[See the associated section of the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations)

Answer (score 0):

`union` is working.

**Sample code is:**

```
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10, 3)
    val pairRDD = rdd.map { x => (x, x) }

    val rdd1 = sparkContext.parallelize(11 to 20, 3)
    val pairRDD1 = rdd1.map { x => (x, x) }

    pairRDD.union(pairRDD1).foreach(tuple => {
      println(tuple._1)
      println(tuple._2)
    })
```